# How do you use the Completed event for a Xamarin Forms Entrycell?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to use a xamarin forms entrycell to retrieve a user's name, however I do not know how to use the completed event to retrieve that information.  Thank you.  There is no code that I can provide as I really don't know what I'm doing.  Thanks.

Comment: Why can you not provide any code? You must have started with something, otherwise you wouldn't be asking this question, I suppose.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
myEntryCell.Completed += CompletedHandler;

protected void CompletedHandler(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
  var username = myEntryCell.Text;
}
```